# NSIS Uninstaller to remove save files

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine, nsis, uninstallation

I am currently using NSIS to create an installer for my app. My app is made using C# (with Unity3D) and I was wondering if there is an equivalent to the two following functions in C# that I am using to save files (save data and such) during the execution of my app, in Python.

I want to know the paths to the save files to be able to remove them in my uninstaller !

Here are the paths :

Save path :

```
Application.persistentDataPath
```

Image path (the user is able to save some pictures in his picture folder) :

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures)
```

Is there a way to get these paths in Python ? Or in my .nsh file (where the uninstall files are listed) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NSIS shell constants are listed in the help file (4.2.3 Constants). You are probably looking for `$APPDATA\YourApp` and `$PICTURES`...

Comment: The $PICTURES constant works perfectly, however my save data is located in the LocalLow folder of my appdata. The $APPDATA points to the roaming data and the $LOCALAPPDATA points to the Local folder. Is there a way to get the LocalLow folder ?

Comment: Manually added a "Low" string variable to the path (so it becomes LocalLow), don't know if this is a good way to go but it works...

Comment: LocalLow is mostly used by Internet Explorer's protected mode, there might be a IE specific API to get that path but there is no NSIS constant for it.